# Facebook Debugger - Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, debugging

All the URLs of the site http://www.lumi7.com.br got the "Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped" with Facebook Debugger at least **2 out of 3 times**. Almost 35% of the time, it gets the right info, with 200 response code. Found it really weird because the hits at the actual links don`t get any errors, only through the Facebook Debugger. The **code for the tags goes as follows** (*wordpress setup... the get_fbimg function is at the funcions.php module and working fine... all information retrieves just fine 100% of the time*)..

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php if (is_single() || is_page()) { echo 'article'; } else { echo 'website';} ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimg(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>   
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1583250550"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="466901323366968"/>
```

Things I've tried:

1. Remove all tags
2. Reinsert them one by one
3. Testing rebuild the .htaccess step by step
4. Changing the links at the tags between https and http
5. Host seems pinging just fine
6. Tested several wordpress plugins (free and premium)
7. Other sites at the same host works fine, tested the same tags with them
8. Tried on default wordpress themes to rule out any possible theme conflicts

The same ratio keeps hitting.. 2 out of 3 times a response code 502 sometimes, but most of the time it's Error Parsing URL.

Some info that might be relevant:

PHP 5.2.17

Apache 2.2.22

MySQL 5.0.91

Perl 5.8.8

Kernel 2.6.18-408.8.2.el5.lve0.8.61.3

server ip 66.7.218.190

don't have shell accesss

Example url at the debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lumi7.com.br%2Fcritica-joao-e-maria-cacadores-de-bruxas%2F

Comment: Maybe this is just bug... Report it to FB

Comment: I'm seeing very similar behavior. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802012/why-cant-the-facebook-debugger-tool-scrape-my-website

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have any updates? Other questions get no answer either, so I'd be glad if you can share a solution…