# Why can't the Facebook Debugger Tool scrape my website?

Tags: facebook

I have a website at http://predictstat.com/. It's powered by Django. I would like to make sure that when a user posts a link from this website onto Facebook, a nice preview image, title and description show up there. This website can also be accessed by using a different domain name: http://percephany.com/. However, I don't really want to use that. I want it to be known to the world as predictstat.com.

To test the Facebook linking/previewing, I have been using the [Facebook Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). These are the meta-tags that are in my index.html page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://predictstat.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://predictstat.com/static/images/predictStatLogo.png" />
<meta property="og:title"       content="predictStat" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Online prediction logging and tracking" />    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

When I ask the Facebook debugger tool to scrape http://predictstat.com/, It gives me the following error:

```
Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

However, when I change the meta tags to refer to percephany.com instead of predictstat.com, and then ask the Facebook Debugger tool to scrape http://percephany.com/, it works perfectly fine.

Why is this the case? Why does the Facebook Debugger tool like the domain name http://percephany.com/, but dislike the domain name http://predictstat.com/ when they both point to the same underlying website?

Comment: This works correctly for me: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpredictstat.com%2F

Comment: Strange. Facebook will share a link to `predictstat.com`, but I also get the errors in the debugger. Usually if the debugger won't parse the page, Facebook also won't share a link. You might want to file a bug report with Facebook on this one.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to file a bug report?

I went to this page: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs
But I don't see any button to file a new bug! Am I loosing my mind?

Comment: The "Create a new bug" link is one of the autocomplete entries in the search box. Facebook wants you to search to see if there are existing bugs that apply before you create a new one.

Comment: Cpilko, I did search. I didn't find what I was looking for. but once you have searched, I still don't see how to create the bug report.

Comment: Is there any solution you came up with?